# Finding dim Sp$\left \{ v_1,v_2,v_3 \right \}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Given $u_1,u_2,u_3,v_1,v_2,v_3 \in V$ such that $u_1,u_2,u_3 \in U= Sp\left \{ v_1,v_2,v_3 \right \}$ and $B=\left \{ u_1-u_2, u_1+3u_3, 4u_2+5u_3 \right \}$ is linearly independent, find dim$U$

---

So because I was given a spanning set of $U$ a wild guess would be proving $\left \{ v_1,v_2,v_3 \right \}$ is linearly independent. However $\alpha v_1+\beta v_2 +\gamma v_3=0$ doesn't really give me anything since I don't see the connection to $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Note that

1. As $U$ is a linear (sub-)space and contains $u_1,u_2,u_3$, it must also contain all linear combinations
   $$\lambda_1u_1+\lambda_2u_2+\lambda_3u_3,$$
   therefore it also contains all the elements of $B$, and so also $\text{span}(B)$.
2. $\text{span}(B)$ is a $3-$dimensional linear subspace of $V$, as $B$ is made of $3$ linearly independent vectors.

Comment: How do you know $V \subseteq  Sp B$?

Comment: I am saying 1. $\text{span}B\subseteq U$ and 2. $\dim(\text{span}B)=3$
I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I think I'm not getting something here. If we want to use $B$ as the basis of $U$ to determine dim$U$, then we must show it spans $U$. If I understood you showed every linear comb. of $B$ is in $U$ but we need to show every element if $U$ is a linear combination of $B$, don't we?

Comment: That would be a possibility, but showing it explicitly would be a mess. Instead the idea is to use a dimension argument: we know that $V$ is a subspace of dimension **less or equal to** $3$, as it is spanned by the $3$ vectors $v_i$. But it also contains a subspace of dimension $3$, hence its dimension must be **at least** $3$. Thus it must be exactly $3$, i.e the vectors $v_i$ are linearly independent

Comment: I need to find dim$U$, not dim$V$. I still don't understand how did you get to that conclusion.

Comment: In my last comment replace the $V$ with $U$. It is a typo. That said, I don't know how to explain it further.

Comment: Maybe this last comment can help you with the conclusion: if two linear subspaces $A,B$ satisfy $A\subset B$ and share the same dimension then $A=B$.

Comment: But how do you actually prove Sp$B$ is a subspace of $U$?? I see why $B \subseteq  U$ but it's not trivial proving $SpB \subseteq  U$ (Or just proving a linear comb. of 2 elements is $B$ is in $U$ for that matter)
Other than that I just want to thank you for sticking with me depiste my stupidity...

Comment: It is simply because $U$ is a linear subspace, and so must contain all linear combinations of contained element, in particular these of $B$.